# LibGdx - Slider not responding to touchUp

Tags: java, slider

I have a problem with **LibGdx's Slider**. Slider's value should be set to 128 every touchUp.
But it work only the first few times. After every time I slide and touch up, value is equal to place where I touch up.

```
joY = new Slider(32, 224, 1, false, skin);
[...]
joY.addListener(new ClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
        joY.setValue(128);
    }
});
```

Any help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [ClickListener](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ClickListener.html%20%22Click) in documentation.

For **touchUp method** it says:

> Called when a mouse button or a finger touch goes up anywhere, but only if touchDown previously returned true for the mouse button or touch.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I looked at it before. This isn't my problem.
I resolve my problem by placing Override function in main loop (before in contructor)
But thanks